# Storage size of sockaddr_in variable isn't known

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, freebsd

I have a piece of code that used to work in some environment a long time ago. I'm pretty sure it was a FreeBSD machine so I got FreeBSD 8.3 and I'm trying to make this file but it's not working.

When I try to compile it it complains with:

```
f.c: In function 'tcp'>
f.c:24: error: storage size of 'socket_stru' isn't known
f.c:29: error: 'IPPROTO_TCP' undeclared (first use in this function)
...
```

I've been looking around and I see these are all specified in the sys/socket.h file. This is my actual file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#include "f.h"

int tcp4 (in_addr_t ip, int port, int qsize )
{   
    struct sockaddr_in socket_stru; // line 24
    socket_stru.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_stru.sin_port = htons(port);
    socket_stru.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;

    int actual_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); // line 29
...
```

I feel like my code somehow doesn't "read" the sys/socket.h file so it doesn't know about socket_stru and IPPROTO_TCP, but I'm just really lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cut and paste your code into a file (removing only the #include f.h and closed off the function call.) It compiles just fine on *Linux*.

I suspect there may be header files differences on BSD.  For socket programming, I typically include ALL these header files.  And I know my socket code compiles on BSD as well.  I suspect one of these header files brings in the definition for sockaddr_in. I recall when I ported by socket code to BSD, I had to explicitly add a few of these.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
/* the next two includes probably aren't relevant for you, but I typically use them all anyway */
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/termios.h>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow. It compiles with all these headers! Now off to take them out one by one until I know which one it is. Thanks!!

Comment: It's `#include <netinet/in.h>`. More details are given here: http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~qiao/courses/cs3mh3/tutorials/socket.html

Answer (score 14):

None of the other answers worked for me. After taking a look inside the `sys/socket.h` file, I didn't even see a definition for `struct sockaddr_in`.

What worked for me was to `#include` one of the following files when using the corresponding `struct sockaddr_*` type:

- if you're using `struct sockaddr_in`,  `#include <netinet/in.h>`
- if you're using `struct sockaddr_un`,  `#include <sys/un.h>`
- if you're using `struct sockaddr_ns`,  `#include <netns/ns.h>`
- if you're using `struct sockaddr_ndd`, `#include <sys/ndd_var.h>`

More information on the header files for socket programming can be found [here](http://ps-2.kev009.com/tl/techlib/manuals/adoclib/aixprggd/progcomc/skthdrs.htm).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but the following include fixed the issue for me

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `#include <resolv.h>` to your source and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

According to [freebsd developer's handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/sockets-essential-functions.html) you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```